# S02E16 "A Matter of Time" How did Daniel suddenly come back?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

So everything was fine until the end. SG-10 plus Daniel got stuck on a planet where gravity was so heavy that time was really slow. As such they were moving so slow that the gate would close before they could enter it. Then... at the end, at main base, they explode a charge to put a spike of energy on the Stargate to make the wormhole bounce the other end to another Stargate.

Suddenly, O'neill wakes up and Daniel is there? It makes no sense, Daniel should be stuck on P3W-451. I understand that he's a main character, but it sucks they had to bend the laws of physics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Daniel isn't with SG-10, he's with SG-6 on another planet.

> **O'NEILL :** ***Daniel's with** [SG-]**6, isn't he?***
>
> **CARTER:** *Yeah, he's on a dig on P3X-808.*
>
> **SIMMONS:** *Computer can't identify the signal. It's not a GDO transmission*

Obviously in reality the line was a throwaway to explain his total absence from the episode, aside from a pre-taped cameo at the end of the show.

Comment: where do you get the transcripts?

Comment: http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/2.15_%22A_Matter_Of_Time%22_Transcript is good for transcripts. Imsdb is better for original scripts